# obj-c pattern to separate model and network-layer

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am trying to improve the design of my applications model initialization and update.

**What I have**

Currently I have a more or less MVC structure with the model classes having most of the variables `readonly` and these can only be updated by sync'zing the app with a server: a json file will be received and a dictionary passed to a predisposed model class method

```
[ModelClass updatewithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)jsonDictionary]
```

but this way all the json keywords and structure, that i believed should be kept wrapped inside the network-layer of my app, have to be handled by the Model.

**An alternative**

One alternative solution is to let the Model be `read/write` and have a Factory/initializer/whatever class which instantiate or update them. This would cause unfortunately to expose the should-be-private members of my model classes.

**What I am looking for**

Is there a Pattern which would impose separation of model from it's instantiation letting information-hiding principle survive and without using proxy-classes (or whatever java-like class-explosion-generating method)? A somewhat `friend` principle in c++.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use DTO protocol?

Comment: Not sure what it is, but if it is a method to deserialize automatically data then i am afraid it's not that easy because the backend services i am using have wacky interfaces and data need to be preprocessed before than init the model. Could you explain a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Basically, DTO is a transfer protocol. So, if you're requesting a resource to a REST service (let say you want to retrieve a list of "Service" object), when the response will arrive, you know how to parse it: in a Service object replicated as NSObject or AnyObject if you are on Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LucaD said in his comment, I would suggest returning some DTO (Data Transfer Object) class from the network layer, then passing that to the model to update.  For example:

```
@interface ModelClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) ...

- (void)synchronizeBasedOnResponse:(ServiceResponse *)response;
@end


@interface ServiceResponse : NSObject // This is the DTO
@property (nonatomic) ...
@end


@interface MyService : NSObject
- (void)synchronizeModel:(ModelClass *)model
                 success:(void(^)(ServiceResponse *response))successBlock
                 failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failureBlock;
@end
```

Then the actual JSON can change (to some degree), and you can insulate the model from that change in your JSON parsing code, either in `MyService` or in some init method of `ServiceResponse`, while keeping the public interface of `ServiceResponse` the same.

Comment: Yes, this is what i was (probably wrongly) calling proxy-object. I see it at the moment as the only real alternative with a big negative aspect of generating a big amount of classes, this depending on the kind of project (expecially small ones) may be not always let it be advantageous in my opinion. If in a while i won't find any better answer ill have to accept this. Thanks.

Comment: @jalone I understand your concern about the proliferation of small classes.  However, (a) you can often reduce the number of classes by using your model classes as members of the response classes, when appropriate (e.g. have a ```ModelClass``` as a member of ```ServiceResponse``` in the above example); and (b) I often don't find having a large number of small classes to be all that awful, since they should generally be easy to understand and insulate your model from your network code.  The main problem I see is duplication, which can be ameliorated by using the model classes in the DTOs.

Comment: Thanks again, i'll try to find an hybrid solution ad-hoc for the current project.